# Parameter for BPEL process

Tags: netbeans, glassfish, esb, bpel, glassfish-esb

I use OpenESB + BPEL. I would like to use some parameter to set system specific settings (path, string constants, etc.). I tried to use a properties file that a simple java class should read up and use with this method (http://wiki.open-esb.java.net/Wiki.jsp?page=BPELSEHowToCallJavaMethods). 
The problem is that I can't create properties file in BPEL project (not supported). So I created a file by hand. But this file is not included in the deployed app.

Is there any working solution for including property file or is there any other method to set parameters on BPEL process?

Thanks,

Hubidubi

UPDATE:
I found that using application variables is the solution. I defined some variable, but I can't figure out how can I use them in BPEL.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC you reference them via a ${VariableName} directive. I used to use them in OpenESB-Netbeans so I know they work...

Check out http://wiki.open-esb.java.net/Wiki.jsp?page=ApplicationConfiguration

Answer (score 0):

Afaik there is also some kind of preferences for a bpel process that you can set in the bpel file. To reference them in your bpel process, there is function `getPreference(key)`. I successfully use this with the Oracle BPEL stuff.